# translation of customized pdfs doesn't work

Tags: magento2, module, localisation, pdf

I created a module called `phil/pdfs` to customize the pdf of `magento_sales` module. Everything works fine but the translation. 
Collecting the phrases with `i18n` tool returns all phrases I want to translate. I put the csv file to

> phil/pdfs/i18n

without success. 
If I change the cvs file to `en_US` the translation works fine. It seems the pdf is generated by the language active in backend. How can I change the translation to language active in storeview?

Somebody knows a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding adding your translation strings to your theme file :

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Like this :

```
"Grand Total","Big Total"
```

*Note : be careful with spaces at the end of some translations*